# output a nice list from a category

Tags: php, sql

i have a table in my database calle "cat". In this is entrys like "game1", "game2", "game3" etc. I wonder how i can output this in a list with a link on each category going to like "http://mypage.com/game1", "http://mypage.com/game2" and so on.

I tried a few mysql output but im just not getting it to work :/

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

# Replace $base_url = "http://mypage.com/" with your Website URL you need to set
$base_url = "http://mypage.com/";

# --- Remove this piece of code, it's for demonstration purpose only
# List of all categories from database "cat" table
foreach(range('Z', 'A') as $char){
    //$categories[$char] = array("$char-Category-1","$char-Category-2");
    $categories[] = "$char-Category-1";
    $categories[] = "$char-Category-2";
}
# --- Remove above code

# $categories will be your database cat table Categories
$category_by_alphabets = array();

foreach ($categories as $cat_name){
    $character = strtoupper(substr($cat_name, 0, 1));
    $category_by_alphabets[$character][] = $cat_name;
}
ksort($category_by_alphabets);
?>

<?php 
    if(!empty($category_by_alphabets) && is_array($category_by_alphabets)):
?>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach($category_by_alphabets as $alphabets => $categories): ?>

            <li> <?php echo $alphabets;?></li>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach($categories as $category_name): ?>
                <li> 
                    <a href="<?php echo $base_url. $category_name;?>"> 
                    <?php echo $category_name;?></a>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: What if there is 500+ categorys and like 10 new get's added daily? is there a way to make it output all the categorys automaticly? in the table "cat" there are a row for each categorys like "game1", "game2" etc. im talking about something like this > http://www.gamewallpapers.com/directory.php

Comment: ok, adding new example with the required output you need, wait.

Comment: check, I just updated the code as per your need. Hope it helps you now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//Array with data from table.
$array = array('game1', 'game2', 'game3', 'game4', 'game5');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
//This shows
//Array
//(
//    [0] => game1
//    [0] => game2
//    [0] => game3
//    [0] => game4
//    [0] => game5
//)

//Now we gonna use the implode() function.
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>' . implode("</li><li>", $array) . '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
//This shows
//   game1
//   game2
//   game3
//   game4
//   game5
?>
```

The `print_r()` function, you mostly use to check with what the array is filled.

The `implode()` function is to push some stuff between every element of the array.

Comment: What if there is 500+ categorys and like 10 new get's added daily? is there a way to make it output all the categorys automaticly? in the table "cat" there are a row for each categorys like "game1", "game2" etc. im talking about something like this > http://www.gamewallpapers.com/directory.php